# Rewrite rule doesn't work in NGINX

Tags: webserver, nginx, rewrite

Consider a URL as shown below:

```
http://myDomain.tld/anAddress/myFile.pdf?X=zzz&Y=kkk
```

How can I have it as :

```
http://myDomain.tld/anAddress/myFile.pdf/zzz/kkk
```

I want to get rid of both `?X` and `&Y`. I'd be glad if someone let me know what rule I should use.

**MY SERVER BLOCK :**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name _;

    location  / {
        root /my/root/path;

        rewrite ^/(.*)pdf/(.*)/(.*)$ /$1?md5=$2&expires=$3 break;

        secure_link $arg_md5,$arg_expires;
        autoindex on;

        secure_link_md5 "$secure_link_expires$uri aWord";

        if ($secure_link = "") { return 403; }
        if ($secure_link = "0") { return 410; }
    }
}
```

---

**Purpose :** To be more precise, my URL is like:

```
http://myDomain.tld/anAddress/myFile.pdf?md5=So1Me2Ha3Sh4&expires=123456789
```

I want it to be like:

```
http://myDomain.tld/anAddress/myFile.pdf/So1Me2Ha3Sh4/123456789
```

In **Apache**, we can use:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)pdf/(.*)/(.*)$ $1?md5=$2&expires=$3
```

When I tried to convert it to NGINX form, it became:

```
rewrite ^/(.*)pdf/(.*)/(.*)$ /$1?md5=$2&expires=$3 break;
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: There are a number of problems with your question. What happens to the `.pdf` text in the original URI? Why is there a `(.*)` in the rewritten URI instead of `expires=`? Where have you placed the `rewrite` rule in your configuration file (because the use of `break` vs `last` is context sensitive)?

Comment: @RichardSmith sorry it was a mistake, it's `expires=` not `(.*)`. I used it in `location ~ / {  ...  }`, and I am not that familiar with rewrite syntax in nginx, so I may have done it wrong.

Comment: You appear to rewrite `myFile.pdf` to `myFile.` (with a trailing `.`). Is the destination URI processed in the same location block?

Comment: @RichardSmith Yes, I only have one block set for this. I'd be glad if you can help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may want to edit your question and add further details, such as your `server` block. You wish to rewrite the URI to `/anAddress/myFile.pdf?md5=So1Me2Ha3Sh4&expires=123456789` - is this a script? Should it have a different extension?

Comment: No, `/anAddress` is a directory in my server root, `myFile` is a file I wanna access, `md5= So1Me2Ha3Sh4` is an exapmle of md5 hash which I got by using secure_link_md5, and `expires=123456789` is secure_link_expires. If you think my server block is needed, I can update my question, but I guess there is no problem with my question since I'm just looking for a rewrite rule since mine doesn't work and I have no idea how I should write this in NGINX.

Comment: @RichardSmith I updated my question, you can check my server block now. Thanks bro.

Comment: Does `myFile` include a `.pdf` extension or not?

Comment: @RichardSmith yes it does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that you are not capturing the last three characters of the filename (i.e. `pdf`) which means that they are missing from the rewritten URI.

You should try moving the `)`, so that the `pdf` is captured as part of `$1`:

```
rewrite ^/(.*pdf)/(.*)/(.*)$ /$1?md5=$2&expires=$3 break;
```

EDIT: In response to your comment, you can add a new location block which matches the URIs you wish to reject, for example:

```
location ~* \.pdf$ {
    return 403;
}
```

The above regular expression location block matches any URI that ends with `.pdf` (with or without a query string). See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

Comment: Mate, thanks you so much!  There is only one question left, it's working but I can still access `myFile.pdf` by using the old URL including `?md5=...&expires=...`, is there any way to return 403 when using that kind of URL instead of the new one?

Comment: I have updated the answer.